# remove default sort from sql query and

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sorting

I want to get records sorted as they are in the query :

```
SELECT `month`, SUM(order_quantity) AS order_quantity FROM" +
            "(  SELECT MONTH(date_livraison) AS month,         COUNT(*) AS order_quantity  FROM" +
            " bon_livraison    GROUP BY MONTH(date_livraison)    UNION ALL      " +
            "SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity      UNION ALL     " +
            " SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL  " +
            "   SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL  " +
            "   SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity    UNION ALL  " +
            "  SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL  " +
            "   SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL  " +
            "   SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL   " +
            "  SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL    " +
            " SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL    " +
            " SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL   " +
            "  SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity     UNION ALL  " +
            "   SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS month, 0 order_quantity ) a GROUP BY `month` ORDER BY `month`
```

but always I have 1....12

do you any idea

**************************EDIT

here is the result when I put `order by 'month desc'` or I add new column and I ordeded by it : 
[image]

if you see, the problem is that the order of order_quantity has the first  priority

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ORDER BY month`?

Comment: Yes because you are ordering by month and grouping by month

Comment: then what is the solution

Comment: @begiPass Use `ORDER BY month DESC`.

Comment: You can include a new constant column (named `o` in sample) in selects and order by it. Sample: `select ..., 1 as o from ... union all select ..., 2 as o from ... union all .. group by o, ... order by o`.

Comment: You were advised to try `order by month desc`, **not `order by 'month desc'`**, which is syntactically a very different thing. Remove the quotation marks for the order to be actually by the `month` column. Or try a different column, like `oo` perhaps (for `month` may not be the right choice), but again, do not put quotation marks like that.